# ogr2ogr not converting negative values when doing json to shp

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr

I have converted a geoJSON file to shp using ogr2ogr, and everything is as expected - except any values that are negative in the JSON end up being positive once the file is converted to shp.

For example :

JSON : "-45" - Correct before converting

SHP  : "45"  - Wrong after converting

Here is the command I have used :

```
ogr2ogr -nlt POLYGON -skipfailures polygons.shp geojsonfile.json
```

Am I missing something? I looked in the documentation for ogr2ogr and I don't see anything about negatives. An actual example for one feature is below. Note the value that is "-7.5", but it is "7.5" after being converted to a shapefile. I confirmed this in QGIS.

```
{
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {      "type": "Polygon",
      "coordinates": [
        [
          [-98.09436584736005, 29.62865606187322],
          [-98.09594335852961, 29.626871027805652],
          [-98.0970915224778, 29.62765563489956],
          [-98.09548731746852, 29.62942243552636],
          [-98.09436584736005, 29.62865606187322]
        ]
      ]
     },
     "properties": {
        "sweep": 0,
        "sweepTime": "2017-02-20T04:40:19Z",
        "elevAngle": 0.6893921,
        "value": -7.5,  // Does not convert properly as a negative value
        "radialAng": 218.172,
        "begGateRan": 10499.548,
        "endGateRan": 10749.536,
        "heightRel": 132.83063,
        "heightASL": 325.769
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Works for me with GDAL 3.1.0dev

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" negative.shp negative.json
Warning 6: Field sweepTime create as date field, though DateTime requested.

ogrinfo negative.shp -al
INFO: Open of `negative.shp'
      using driver `ESRI Shapefile' successful.

Layer name: negative
Metadata:
  DBF_DATE_LAST_UPDATE=2020-03-23
Geometry: Polygon
Feature Count: 1
Extent: (-98.097092, 29.626871) - (-98.094366, 29.629422)
Layer SRS WKT:
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["latitude",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        AXIS["longitude",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    ID["EPSG",4326]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
sweep: Integer (9.0)
sweepTime: Date (10.0)
elevAngle: Real (24.15)
value: Real (24.15)
radialAng: Real (24.15)
begGateRan: Real (24.15)
endGateRan: Real (24.15)
heightRel: Real (24.15)
heightASL: Real (24.15)
OGRFeature(negative):0
  sweep (Integer) = 0
  sweepTime (Date) = 2017/02/20
  elevAngle (Real) = 0.689392100000000
  value (Real) = -7.500000000000000
  radialAng (Real) = 218.171999999999997
  begGateRan (Real) = 10499.548000000000684
  endGateRan (Real) = 10749.536000000000058
  heightRel (Real) = 132.830630000000014
  heightASL (Real) = 325.769000000000005
  POLYGON ((-98.0943658473601 29.6286560618732,-98.0959433585296 29.6268710278057,-98.0970915224778 29.6276556348996,-98.0954873174685 29.6294224355264,-98.0943658473601 29.6286560618732))
```

Comment: Well, this is odd. I am not an expert with gdal by any means, but I don't see what I could have done wrong. I am using gdal through conda - version 3.0.4 from this year.  Surely that isn't old enough to cause an issue.

Comment: Does `ogrinfo geojsonfile.json -al` show the value with minus sign? Does conversion into GeoPackage work as supposed?